# Time & Work / Percentage Problem : Find percentage of trees planted.

Tags: contest-math, percentages

> In a field, two workers are planting trees. After sometime, a third
> worker is added and the number of trees planted becomes half as large.
> How many trees can the second worker plant as a percentage of the
> number of trees planted by first worker if it is given that efficiency
> of second worker is $\frac{1}{3}$ of $1st$ and $3rd$ worker combined.

My solution approach :-
Let the first worker be $W_{1}$ who can plant $x$ tress in $1$ unit of time.
Let the second worker be $W_{2}$ who can plant $y$ tress in $1$ unit of time.
Let the third worker be $W_{3}$ who can plant $z$ tress in $1$ unit of time.

Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be working together for $t$ units of time before $W_{3}$ joined and hence the number of trees planted by  $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ will be $(x+y)t$.

After $t$ units of time, $W_{3}$ joined them and all three together worked for next $T$ minutes and hence the number of trees planted by $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ and $W_{3}$ will be $(x+y+z)T$.

Total time taken = $t+T$
Total trees planted = $(x+y)t + (x+y+z)T$

As per question (the number of trees planted becomes half as large after $W_{3}$ joined $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$);
  $(x+y)t + (x+y+z)T = 1.5(x+y)t$
$\Rightarrow 2(x+y+z)T = (x+y)t$

Efficiency of $W_{1}$ will be $x$.
Efficiency of $W_{2}$ will be $y$.
Efficiency of $W_{3}$ will be $z$.

As per question (it is given that efficiency of second worker is $\frac{1}{3}$ of $1st$ and $3rd$ worker combined);
$3y = (x+z)$

After this I am not able to think how can we get to remove the variable $t$ and $T$ from the problem. Can someone please help me with this? I've been stuck with this for a while.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You definitely seem to be missing some data

Comment: That's all that has been given in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let trees planted by first worker be $x$, by second be $y$ and by third be $z$.

It is given that "a third worker is added and the number of trees planted becomes half as large" thus we can make this equation.

$$ \frac{x+y}{2}=z $$

and.
Now see for the second equation the question is asking "How many trees can the second worker plant as a percentage of the number of trees planted by first worker if it is given that efficiency of second worker is 1/3 of 1st and 3rd worker combined" which means it is asking that if we time is same and they work together then percent of B's work in term of A.

So,

$$ \frac{x}{t} + \frac{z}{t} = \frac{3y}{t}  $$

Cancelling all t from denominator,

$$ x+z=3y $$

Now first of all let us reduce both equation in terms of $x$ and $y$.

Substitute value of z from equation $1$ in equation $2$

You get $3x=5y$

$$ \frac{y}{x} = \frac{3}{5} $$

Now just multiply 100 by both sides to get the answer.

Comment: +1 to your answer.  I think that the original problem is very poorly worded.  Your answer hinges on $z = (x+y)/2.$  I agree with this interpretation.  However, that doesn't deflect from the ambiguity in such a poorly worded problem.

Comment: Can you please explain what I did wrong in my solution approach? And why have you not considered the time parameter as we do not certainly know the units of time they have been working?

Comment: @Ganit this was the wrong approach. You can't solve the question because you haven't been given any idea regarding time so your first thought must be to solve the question without using time parameter like I did in my question I ignored the time parameter and got the right answer

Comment: May I know the reason for the downvote pls?

Comment: @Ganit now have you understood or any more doubts?

Comment: @JitendraSingh : I am sorry but I didn't downvoted. It was done by mistake. I am unable to upvote this now as it is showing me the error message "You last voted on this answer 13 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."
Also your answer is good but I have one small doubt. How did you write the 1st equation? Also the 2nd equation should be of efficiency and the efficiency is $\frac{Total Work Done}{Total Time Taken}$ and the time taken will be same for first 2 workers but it will be different for the $3rd$ worker, then how can you equate the number of trees planted?

Comment: @Ganit for the downvote its okay as long as the downvoter writes the reason for his downvote I am fairly satisfied. For the second part I have edited my question and you can now remove your downvote. And this action will give you +1 and me +2 or +12. For the third and fourth part please see the edit I have described how the equations are formed by taking lines from question which helped me make these equation. Also I have described why I didn't taken time in efficiency because at end of question they were asking to find B% trees in term of A when **all of them work together**

Comment: which means everyone is using same time and thus time will get cancelled. This is a continuation of my previous comment

Comment: ohhh...okkk.now I got it...thanks for the lucid explanation.

Comment: @Ganit good to know my answer helped you